# Finding lost Thieves Guild armour

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have misplaced my thieves guild armour and this is an issue as i need to hand it into tonilia to be upgraded to allow me to get the guild master armour so i can complete the thieves guild questline and get the trophy. Anyone any idea on how to reacquire the armour? i think i gave it to faendal but i cannot find him anywhere in Riverwood and i have checked Whiterun hall of the dead and he is not there so i am clueless as to where he is. he isn't my current follower as i have Lydia following me. Any help/suggestions?

Comment: I Play on PS4. So i cannot use console commands... unfortuantely.

Answer (score 4):

There should be spare pieces of Thieves Guild armor in the Cistern, unless you've misplaced/sold those too.  Start your search in the room with all the lock-picking-practice-chests.

Comment: Also, these respawn, so even you do pick them up and misplace them you can just wait out the respawn timer to continue the quest chain